# Package Searching in Prolog

Tags: list, search, comparison, prolog, package

I have the following packages:

```
package('python', '2.6.5').
package('python', '2.5.4').
package('python', '1.5.2').
package('python', '3.1.0').
```

And I wrote some basic functions in Prolog, they are below:

```
% Integer-like-atom <-> integer
atom_integer(Atom, Int) :- atom_chars(Atom, C), number_chars(Int, C).

% Split an atom around a separator
% split, split2, split3 from: http://gollem.swi.psy.uva.nl/SWI-Prolog/mailinglist/archive/old/0164.html
split(A,B,C):-
 atom_chars(A,AC),
 atom_chars(B,BC),
 append(BC,AC,BAC),
 split3(AC,BAC,ABAC),
 split2(AC,ABAC,C), !.

split3(AC,BAC,NewABAC):-
 append(AC,ABAC,BAC),split3(AC,ABAC,NewABAC).
split3(_,ABAC,ABAC).

split2(_,[],[]).
split2(X,Y,[A|O]):- 
 append(Z,X,ZX),append(ZX,R,Y),atom_chars(A,Z),
 split3(X,R,NewR),
 split2(X,NewR,O).

split_version(Ver, VParts) :- split('.', Ver, VParts).

%%% integer_list/2
integer_list([], []).
integer_list([Lst1|RLst1], [Lst2|RLst2]) :-
    atom_integer(Lst1, Lst2),
    integer_list(RLst1, RLst2).


%%% cmp_list/3
cmp_list([A], [B], Cmp) :-
    A > B,
    Cmp = gt.

cmp_list([A], [B], Cmp):-
    A < B,
    Cmp = lt.

cmp_list([A], [B], Cmp):-
    A >= B,
    Cmp = ge.

cmp_list([A], [B], Cmp):-
    A =< B,
    Cmp = le.

cmp_list([], [B], Cmp):-
    Cmp = le.

cmp_list([], [B], Cmp):-
    Cmp = lt.

cmp_list([A], [], Cmp):-
    Cmp = ge.

cmp_list([A], [], Cmp):-
    Cmp = gt.

cmp_list([X|XS], [Y|YS], Cmp):-
    X > Y,
    cmp_list([X], [Y], Cmp).

cmp_list([X|XS], [Y|YS], Cmp):-
    X == Y,
    cmp_list(XS, YS, Cmp).


%%% cmp_version/3
cmp_version(V1, V2, Cmp):-
    split_version(V1, Lst1),
    split_version(V2, Lst2),
    integer_list(Lst1, IntLst1),
    integer_list(Lst2, IntLst2),
    cmp_list(IntLst1, IntLst2, Cmp).
```

Now, I want to write a satis_req/3 function to get the following stuff:

```
?- satis_req('python', '3', le, V).
V = '2.6.5' ;
V = '2.5.4' ;
V = '1.5.2' .

?- satis_req('python', '2.5.4', gt, V).
V = '2.6.5' ;
V = '3.1.0' .
```

The code below was written by myself, but there's an error occurs when I call it.

```
satis_req(Language, V1, Cmp, V2):-
    V2 = package(Language, V),
    write(V2),
    nl,
    cmp_version(V1, V2, Cmp).
```

Anyone can help me make this function correct please?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified a bit your program, using ISO [Standard Order of Terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.7.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compare.html%27%29%29) for comparison:

```
package(python, '2.6.5').
package(python, '2.5.4').
package(python, '1.5.2').
package(python, '3.1.0').

satis_req(Language, V1, Cmp, V2):-
    package(Language, V2),
    compare(R, V2, V1),
    match(Cmp, R).

match(lt, (<)).
match(gt, (>)).
match(le, (=<)).
match(le, (<)).
match(ge, (>=)).
match(ge, (>)).
match(eq, (==)).
match(ne, (\==)).
match(ne, (<)).
match(ne, (>)).
```

test:

```
?- satis_req('python', '3', le, V).
V = '2.6.5' ;
V = '2.5.4' ;
V = '1.5.2' ;
false.

?- satis_req('python', '2.5.4', gt, V).
V = '2.6.5' ;
V = '3.1.0'.
```

And in SWI-Prolog there is an [easier way to split](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3) an atom around a separator, but I'm not using it in the code above.

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L, '.', '2.5.4').
L = ['2', '5', '4'].
```

A last note: [compare](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3) works as expected for *complex* terms, including lists, there is no point to write your own, if you don't have some *strange* requirement. You could instead think about a *normalized* version representation: i.e. '3' should be normalized to '3.0.0' before passing it down.

Anyway, here a correction for your last predicate (Prolog hasn't *functions*):

```
satis_req(Language, V1, Cmp, V2):-
    package(Language, V2),
    write(V2),
    nl,
    cmp_version(V1, V2, Cmp).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! For the correction of my predicate, actually I did try that way before my post, but it doesn't work at all. It seems that the "cmp_list/3" predicates above are incorrect. Do you know how to fix it please?

Comment: why do not use compare/3? your Prolog doesn't have it?

Comment: I don't quite understand compare/3, what does the atom "R" in compare/3 mean??

Comment: R stand for Relation, it's a symbol that you set, to use the predicate in 'usual' way, or leave variable, to get from Prolog the relation.